# Remote Desktop Manager

Tags: remote-desktop

The [OSX remote desktop application](https://www.apple.com/au/remotedesktop/) has a handy feature where you are able to translate an IP (such as `10.10.1.1`) or DNS Entry (such as `myprimarydc.localdomain.com`) into a user-friendly name such as `My Primary DC`.

On a windows PC, [whilst it is possible to create User-Friendly shortcuts for servers and PC's](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-a-remote-desktop-connection-shortcut-windows), they are not stored as such in the `mstsc` application itself. I am looking for a free option to manage my remote desktop connections. To summarize, I'd like the following features:

1. Central storage of remote connections
2. Ability to store shortcuts via a user-friendly name
3. Ability to cache credentials on a shortcut.

Potential Candidates that meet my requirements:

1. [nRemoteNG](https://mremoteng.org/)
2. [Remote Desktop Manager 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989)
3. [Terminals](https://terminals.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Izzy I've updated the question and added "potential candidates", with three applications that _might_ meet the OP requirements. I assume there is no issue with performing this?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow sounds reasonable now, so I've reopened it. Thanks for helping out!